# How does one provide or target different data to DOM elements of one kind and does manage / maintain each of an element's rerender / update cycle?

Tags: javascript, dom, data-binding, components, rendering

I'm working on a page on my wordpress site where i pull data from the backend. The data has an `end_date` column that i use to display a countdown timer i.e. from the current date time till the `end_date`.

This is how i approach it:

This is the html element that will display the timer:

`<div class="t1-auction-timer"></div>`

This is the javascript that creates the timer:

```
var countDownDate = new Date("<?=$endDate?>").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    var timer = document.querySelectorAll(".t1-auction-timer");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < timer.length; i++) 
    {
        timer[i].innerHTML = '<ul class="clock-value"><li class="clock-days">' + padNumber(days) + '<small>days</small> </li><li class="clock-separator">:</li><li class="clock-hours">  ' + padNumber(hours) + ' <small>hrs</small> </li><li class="clock-separator">:</li><li class="clock-minutes"> ' + padNumber(minutes) + ' <small>min</small> </li><li class="clock-separator">:</li><li class="clock-seconds"> ' + padNumber(seconds) + ' <small>sec</small> </li></ul>';
    }
    
    if ( distance < 0 )
    {
        clearInterval(x);
                    
        for (var i = 0; i < timer.length; i++) 
        {
            timer[i].innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
        }
    }
}, 1000);

function padNumber(number) 
{
    if( number == 0 )
    {
        number = "0" + number;
    }
    else if( number > 9 )
    {
        number;
    }
    else
    {
        number = "0" + number;    
    }

    return number;
}
```

The `<?=$endDate?>` variable is passed from php. Its being passed correctly.

The number of timers to be displayed will be dynamic depending on the records in the database. The issue I'm facing is: I only get timer created from the first record. Its duplicated across all posts being displayed on the page. I suspect this has to do with my `.t1-auction-timer` class loop but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: 1/2 If I understand correctly, there are most likely more than just one *auction timer* elements displayed at the same time which also count down each to a different end date. In this case I suggest to provide the auction specific `endDate` value together with the timer markup which also is semantically much better.

Comment: 2/2 Something like ... `<time class="t1-auction-timer" datetime="<?=$endDate?>"><?=$endDate?></time>` ...  The client side code then can read this end date from each timer's `datetime` attribute and provide back the correct calculation for each timer via e.g. `... .innerHTML = "<ul>...</ul>"` as shown with the OP's example code.

Comment: hi @PeterSeliger working on your suggestion. will revert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach which uses the `data` attribute.

```js
var auctionTimer = document.getElementsByClassName('t1-auction-timer');

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  
if(auctionTimer.length == 0 ){clearFunction()}
  
for(var i= 0; i < auctionTimer.length; i++){
  var endDate = auctionTimer[i].getAttribute('data-end-date')
  var int = createTimer(endDate, auctionTimer[i]);
   }
},1000)


function clearFunction() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}


function createTimer(endDate, element){
  
var countDownDate = new Date(endDate).getTime();
var now = new Date().getTime();
var distance = countDownDate - now;
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
element.innerHTML = '<ul class="clock-value"><li class="clock-days">' + padNumber(days) + '<small>days</small> </li><li class="clock-separator">:</li><li class="clock-hours">  ' + padNumber(hours) + ' <small>hrs</small> </li><li class="clock-separator">:</li><li class="clock-minutes"> ' + padNumber(minutes) + ' <small>min</small> </li><li class="clock-separator">:</li><li class="clock-seconds"> ' + padNumber(seconds) + ' <small>sec</small> </li></ul>';

  if ( distance < 0 )
{
    if (  element.classList.contains("t1-auction-timer") ){
          element.classList.remove("t1-auction-timer")
          element.classList.add("expierd")
          expierd()
    
    }
}
}       
function padNumber(number) 
{
if( number == 0 )
{
    number = "0" + number;
}
else if( number > 9 )
{
    number;
}
else
{
    number = "0" + number;    
}

return number;
}

function expierd(){
  var expierdDate = document.getElementsByClassName('expierd');
  for(var i= 0; i < expierdDate.length; i++){
expierdDate[i].innerHTML = "expierd"
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="t1-auction-timer" data-end-date="2021-01-03 16:15"></div>
<div class="t1-auction-timer" data-end-date="2021-01-01 16:15"></div>
<div class="t1-auction-timer" data-end-date="2021-01-04 16:15"></div>
```

Comment: As a matter of style, if one suggests the usage of the `data` attribute for providing necessary information, one should read as well such an element node's data via its `dataset` object. The line `var endDate = auctionTimer[i].getAttribute('data-end-date')` then changes to `var endDate = auctionTimer[i].dataset.endDate` or even `const { endDate } = auctionTimer[i].dataset`

Comment: @suo ... Note: This approach does not solve the problem of how to clear the interval after all of the timers have reached their *expired* state; it does not even provide this state to a timer. Thus the interval will run forever. In addition it does not make the best use of `setInterval` either by e.g. providing an anonymous function which does unnecessarily create an additional closure due to ignoring that one can pass the arguments of any function to be run in an interval already to `setInterval` itself.

Comment: @suo i have added clearInterval :) ...@Peter Seliger

Comment: @StefanAvramovic was actually just about to reply. I have my own implementation for  clearing the interval in place. Quite similar to Stefan's version. Thanks guys for your invaluable input :)

Answer (score 1):

An approach which directly uses a lot from the OP's code almost unchanged does, within an interval, process a collection of timer elements by (re)rendering each timer again and again.

A timer element's markup base will be the already above (in the comments) mentioned `<time/>` element where the the OP's `endDate` will be retrieved from this element's `datetime` attribute (also again and again) ...

```js
function padNumber(number) {
  return (number >= 10) && number || `0${ number }`;
}

function updateTimer(nodeList, timer, timerData) {
  // GUARD
  if (timer.dataset.isExpired === "true") {
    return;
  }
  const countDownDate = new Date(timer.dateTime).getTime();
  const now = new Date().getTime();
  const distance = countDownDate - now;

  const days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  const hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  const minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  const seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  
  if (distance >= 0) {
    timer.innerHTML = `<ul class="clock-value">
      <li class="clock-days">${ padNumber(days) } <small>days</small></li>
      <li class="clock-hours">${ padNumber(hours) } <small>hrs</small></li>
      <li class="clock-minutes">${ padNumber(minutes) } <small>min</small></li>
      <li class="clock-seconds">${ padNumber(seconds) } <small>sec</small></li>
     </ul>`;
  } else {
    timer.innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    timer.dataset.isExpired = "true";

    // clear the interval only in case each timer has been expired.
    if ([
      ...nodeList
    ].every(elmNode =>
      elmNode.dataset.isExpired === "true"
    )) {
      clearInterval(timerData.timerId);
    }
  }
}     

function updateAllTimers(nodeList, timerData) {
  nodeList.forEach(timer => updateTimer(nodeList, timer, timerData));
}
function initializeAllTimers() {
  const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.t1-auction-timer');
  const data = {
    timerId: null
  };
  updateAllTimers(nodeList, data);

  data.timerId = setInterval(updateAllTimers, 1000, nodeList, data);
}

initializeAllTimers();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  padding: 2px 10px 3px 10px;
}
li .auction-name {
  font-family: courier;
}

ul.clock-value,
ul.clock-value > li {
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.clock-value > li {
  font-family: ui-monospace;
}
ul.clock-value li:not(:last-child) small:after {
  content: ":";
  display: inline-block;
  width: .7em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    Auction <span class="auction-name">Foo</span> expires at/in ...
    <time class="t1-auction-timer" datetime="2020-12-21 22:15">2020-12-21 22:15</time>
  </li>
  <li>
    Auction <span class="auction-name">Bar</span> expires at/in ...
    <time class="t1-auction-timer" datetime="2020-12-22 03:15">2020-12-22 03:15</time>
  </li>
  <li>
    Auction <span class="auction-name">Baz</span> expires at/in ...
    <time class="t1-auction-timer" datetime="2020-12-22 11:30">2020-12-22 11:30</time>
  </li>
  <li>
    Auction <span class="auction-name">Biz</span> expires at/in ...
    <time class="t1-auction-timer" datetime="2020-12-22 14:45">2020-12-22 14:45</time>
  </li>
  <li>
    Auction <span class="auction-name">Buz</span> expires at/in ...
    <time class="t1-auction-timer" datetime="2020-12-23 10:20">2020-12-23 10:20</time>
  </li>
  <li>
    Auction <span class="auction-name">Fiz</span> expires at/in ...
    <time class="t1-auction-timer" datetime="2020-12-24 10:55">2020-12-24 10:55</time>
  </li>
  <li>
    Auction <span class="auction-name">Faz</span> expires at/in ...
    <time class="t1-auction-timer" datetime="2021-01-04 16:15">2021-01-04 16:15</time>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The above approach might be changed towards creating a list of already pre-rendered timer components where each component's update is not anymore based on assigning a huge piece of always newly created HTML markup to a DOM node's `innerHTML`.

In order to enable a more generic / flexible usage of such components, one now can pass a template-string of custom timer-markup as well as a custom "expired" message to the initializing method. In addition any component now gets identified by its `data-countdown-component` attribute which makes the creation / initialization process independent from any forced or just layout-related CSS class-names.

```js
function emptyElementNode(elmNode) {
  Array
    .from(elmNode.childNodes)
    .forEach(node => node.remove());
}
function createTemplateFromMarkup(templateMarkup) {
  const container = document.createElement('div');
  container.innerHTML = String(templateMarkup);

  return container.firstElementChild;
}

function getTimeMeasureFromMilliseconds(value) {
  let days = (value / 3600000 / 24);  
  let hours = ((days - Math.floor(days)) * 24);
  let minutes = ((hours - Math.floor(hours)) * 60);
  let seconds = ((minutes - Math.floor(minutes)) * 60);

  days = Math.floor(days);
  hours = Math.floor(hours);
  minutes = Math.floor(minutes);
  seconds = Math.floor(seconds + 0.001);

  seconds = ((seconds < 60) && seconds) || 0;
  minutes = ((minutes < 60) && minutes) || 0;
  hours = ((hours < 24) && hours) || 0;

  return { days, hours, minutes, seconds };
}
function formatMeasure(value) {
  return ((value >= 10) && value || `0${ value }`);
}

function createTimerComponent(rootNode, template, expiredMessage) {
  const expirationDate = new Date(rootNode.dateTime);
  const [
    elmDays,
    elmHours,
    elmMinutes,
    elmSeconds
  ] = [...template.querySelectorAll([
    '[data-countdown-days]',
    '[data-countdown-hours]',
    '[data-countdown-minutes]',
    '[data-countdown-seconds]',
  ].join(','))];

  const component = {
    rootNode,
    elmDays,
    elmHours,
    elmMinutes,
    elmSeconds,
    isExpired: false,
    expiredMessage,
    expiresTimestamp: expirationDate.getTime(),
  };
  emptyElementNode(component.rootNode);

  rootNode.dateTime = expirationDate.toUTCString();
  rootNode.appendChild(template);

  return component;
}

function updateTimer(componentList, component, timerData) {
  // GUARD
  if (component.isExpired) {
    return;
  }
  const { dateNow } = timerData;
  const { expiresTimestamp } = component;
  const { elmDays, elmHours, elmMinutes, elmSeconds } = component;

  const time = (expiresTimestamp - dateNow);
  if (time >= 0) {
    const measures = getTimeMeasureFromMilliseconds(time);

    elmSeconds.textContent = formatMeasure(measures.seconds);
    elmMinutes.textContent = formatMeasure(measures.minutes);
    elmHours.textContent = formatMeasure(measures.hours);
    elmDays.textContent = formatMeasure(measures.days);

  } else {
    component.isExpired = true;

    emptyElementNode(component.rootNode);
    component.rootNode.textContent = component.expiredMessage;

    // clear the interval only in case each timer has been expired.
    if (componentList.every(item => item.isExpired)) {

      clearInterval(timerData.timerId);
    }
  }
}

function updateAllTimers(componentList, timerData) {
  timerData.dateNow = Date.now();

  componentList.forEach(component =>
    updateTimer(componentList, component, timerData)
  );
}
function initializeAllTimers(templateMarkup, expiredMessage = 'Closed') {
  const defaultTemplateMarkup = [
    '<span>',
    '<span data-countdown-days></span> <small>days</small>, ',
    '<span data-countdown-hours></span> <small>hours</small>, ',
    '<span data-countdown-minutes></span> <small>minutes</small>, ',
    '<span data-countdown-seconds></span> <small>seconds</small>',
    '</span>',
  ].join('');

  let template = createTemplateFromMarkup(templateMarkup);
  if (!template || template.querySelectorAll([

    '[data-countdown-days]',
    '[data-countdown-hours]',
    '[data-countdown-minutes]',
    '[data-countdown-seconds]',

  ].join(',')).length !== 4) {

    template = createTemplateFromMarkup(defaultTemplateMarkup);
  }
  const componentList = [
    ...document.querySelectorAll('[data-countdown-component]')
  ].map(elmNode =>
    createTimerComponent(elmNode, template.cloneNode(true), expiredMessage)
  );
  const data = {
    timerId: null,
    dateNow: null,
  };
  updateAllTimers(componentList, data);

  data.timerId = setInterval(updateAllTimers, 1000, componentList, data);
}

initializeAllTimers(`<ul class="clock-value">
  <li class="clock-days">
    <span data-countdown-days></span> <small>days</small>
  </li>
  <li class="clock-hours">
    <span data-countdown-hours></span> <small>hours</small>
  </li>
  <li class="clock-minutes">
    <span data-countdown-minutes></span> <small>minutes</small>
  </li>
  <li class="clock-seconds">
    <span data-countdown-seconds></span> <small>seconds</small>
  </li>
</ul>`, 'Expired');
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  padding: 2px 10px 3px 10px;
}
li .auction-name {
  font-family: courier;
}

ul.clock-value,
ul.clock-value > li {
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.clock-value > li {
  font-family: ui-monospace;
}
ul.clock-value li:not(:last-child) small:after {
  content: ":";
  display: inline-block;
  width: .7em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    Auction <span class="auction-name">Foo</span> expires at/in ...
    <time data-countdown-component datetime="2020-12-21 22:15">2020-12-21 22:15</time>
  </li>
  <li>
    Auction <span class="auction-name">Bar</span> expires at/in ...
    <time data-countdown-component datetime="2020-12-22 03:15">2020-12-22 03:15</time>
  </li>
  <li>
    Auction <span class="auction-name">Baz</span> expires at/in ...
    <time data-countdown-component datetime="2020-12-22 11:30">2020-12-22 11:30</time>
  </li>
  <li>
    Auction <span class="auction-name">Biz</span> expires at/in ...
    <time data-countdown-component datetime="2020-12-22 14:45">2020-12-22 14:45</time>
  </li>
  <li>
    Auction <span class="auction-name">Buz</span> expires at/in ...
    <time data-countdown-component datetime="2020-12-23 10:20">2020-12-23 10:20</time>
  </li>
  <li>
    Auction <span class="auction-name">Fiz</span> expires at/in ...
    <time data-countdown-component datetime="2020-12-24 10:55">2020-12-24 10:55</time>
  </li>
  <li>
    Auction <span class="auction-name">Faz</span> expires at/in ...
    <time data-countdown-component datetime="2021-01-04 16:15">2021-01-04 16:15</time>
  </li>
</ul>
```